# What is the way to use `errorElement` prop in react-router-dom when `Routes` component is also used together?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

With react-router-dom v6, I've been trying to make a fallback error element that can be used everywhere if any component throws an error.

And also decided to use DataRouter(`createbrowserrouter`) and `<Routes/>` component together because I need to use `useBlocker` which requires DatarRouter.

But the `errorElement` component doesn't seem to work when I use  component.

I cannot move all the route components into createBrowserRouter method since it requires a great amount of change and also related to conditional route based on the permissions.

Is there any way to declare `errorElement` once at the top and use it with this structure?

Here is the simplified codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mestorf-x0qxwr?file=/src/Root.jsx

And I saw that using DataRouter and `<Routes/>` together is not the best way according to the document, but as I said, I cannot move all routes to the root level. Would there be any caveats?

Comment: The code in your sandbox doesn't appear to run. Also, what is the use case, or benefit, for using a data router but all the routes are declared outside it so they can't use any of the data APIs? I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to do with the code in the sandbox to even fix it so it is runnable.

Comment: Ok, component's `One` and `Two` are named exports and `Root.jsx` is default importing them. Fix the imports to also be named imports and the sandbox runs. Can you [edit] to more clearly explain the use case though? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry for the broken code. I just edited and added comments to make it more explicit. As I mentioned, I wanted to make all components located under DataRouter. Still, the change is too significant and also related to some conditions such as auth, and permissions whether the path is accessible to a user or not. It doesn't seem easy to do at the one top root component because some data that determines whether to render the path depends on the props from the parent component or outside source.

Comment: If you want the root `errorElement` to catch errors thrown in components then their routes should be declared in `createBrowserRouter` if I'm not mistaken. See this [sandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/what-is-the-way-to-use-errorelement-prop-in-react-router-dom-when-routes-com-ncg33c?file=/src/browserRouter.js). The `"/a"` path also catches the error locally and renders *its* own `errorElement`.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes it will work if all components are located in `createBrowserRouter` function, which aren't in my case :( I found one way but seems a bit hacky. It is assigning a defaultProps for `Route` component before exporting. It goes like `Route.defaultProps = {errorElement: <ErrorHandler />}`